# Let $E$ be an inner product space and $\lim x_n = x$, $\lim y_n = y$. Is it true that $\lim \langle x_n, y_n \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inner-products

Let $(E, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be an inner product space, and $(x_n),(y_n)$ sequences such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n = y$ w.r.t to the induced norm. We define a sequence $(z_n)$ by $z_n := \langle x_n, y_n \rangle$.

> My question: Is it true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = \langle x, y \rangle$$

I guess that it holds, but I've not come up with a proof. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. Hint: note that
$$|\langle x_n, y_n \rangle-\langle x, y \rangle|
\leq |\langle x_n, y_n-y \rangle|+|\langle x_n-x, y\rangle|$$
and finally apply the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality).

Comment: And use that the sequence $(x_n)$, being convergent, is bounded.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it holds, because [the bilinear map $(x,y)\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371925) and continuous maps map convergent sequences into convergent sequences.